# Value category of defaulted assignment operator - lvalue or rvalue? (clang vs gcc)

Tags: c++, expression, c++17, language-lawyer, value-categories

Consider the following code:

```
struct S 
{ 
    S& operator=(const S&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    &(S() = S());
}
```

GCC (trunk) complains with:

> ```
>   error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]
>     8 |     &(S() = S());
>       |      ~~~~~^~~~~~
> ```

I found the above error surprising, as I would expect an `S&` return type to produce an lvalue expression. Clang (trunk), on the other hand, accepts the code without any error or warning.

[**live on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aPa3oj)

- **What compiler is correct here?**
- **Is `S() = S()` an rvalue or an lvalue?**

Comment: interestingly, older GCCs use the error message "taking the address of a temporary", rather than "an rvalue". Perhaps this hints at what it's doing -- the assignment operator returns the LHS, which is a temporary, which you're then trying to take the address of?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59950

Comment: ^^ is correct, this was a gcc bug. Fixed for 9.5/10.4/11.3/12.1 and later releases.